# Need some help - installing multi-node OPenstack with Juju and Maas

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, cloud

I am trying to install multi-node OPenstack using Juju and Mass. Juju initializes 4 nodes and they all come up clean but get stuck at relations - attached picture for reference.

[image]

Thanks in advance for help with this